# Is it possible to animate a character that is using the multi-res modifier

Tags: modeling, retopology, multiresolution

I'm trying to create some characters but I want to keep the details from the sculpt. If I use the multi-res modifier without applying it can I animate the character without any issues?

Comment: Yes you can but have you thought about baking the details onto a low-poly version? It would make the objects much lighter...

Answer (score 0):

Yes place the armature modifier before the multires modifier.

To increase performance, disable the multires modifier for the viewport.